# Difference between "by this way" and "in this way"

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

Is the bellow sentence correct?

> Are all errors detectable **by this way**?

What would be the difference between **by this way** and **in this way**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In** this way (or manner); **by** this method.